# pandas pivot_table() puts an unwanted column in my dataframe when I write it to excel why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am making a pivot table from an excel sheet with dozens of columns. I get a 3rd column from the excel sheet even though it's not in my code anywhere.

Data looks like this

Source IP, Destination IP,Zones,Connections,P/D,Comments,Location, Hours,BACKUP,DATACOURCE

1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,DATACENTER,3,P,Decom,FL,5X5,Mirror,Cloud

3.3.3.3,2.2.2.2,Office,45,D,Active,ME,24X7,RAID,Local

1.1.1.1,4.4.4.4,Office,33,P,Active,CA,1X3,RAID,Cloud

Manually did the pivot table in Excel.  Tried various arguments to get rid of it.

```
    fw_files = filedialog.askopenfilename()  #here we grab a filename to parse
    df = pd.read_excel(fw_files)
    df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Source IP', 'Destination IP'])# lose the duplicates
    df3 = df2[df2['''P/D'''].str.contains('P', na=False)] #only flagged P and don't puke on NAN
    df4 = pd.pivot_table(df3, index=['Source IP', 'Destination IP'])# pivot on my two values
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fw_files + '-PIVOT.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'RAW_DATA')
    df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'SOURCE_TO_DESTINATION')
    writer.save()
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

Source IP          Destination IP

10.120.160.71     172.1.12.5

172.1.1.5

ACTUAL Results.  I don't know why the connection column appears but it's correct from the excel sheet

Source IP     Destination IP     Connections

10.120.160.71     172.1.12.8      3

172.34.4.5      45

Answer (score 2):

If you can add some more source data to get us to expected results that may be helpful.  My guess is that what you're getting is because you're not excluding the "connections" column anywhere.  Read Excel will pull all columns by default, if that column is in your dataframe the pivot_table is most likely defaulting to aggregating it for you because it's numeric.

You could try defining your dataframe to only columns you want.  This should at least point you in the right direction.

```
df3 = df2.loc[df2['''P/D'''].str.contains('P', na=False), df2.columns.intersection(['Source IP', 'Destination IP'])]
```

## Edit for additional output thoughts

I'm not really sure why you're pivoting with only an index as generally pivoting will be used to aggregate.  I think you should be able to group since you don't seem to want an aggregation.  If you want the output to look like that specifically you can set index and export.  The output will look a little goofy but it'll leave the gap between source values in the same format you have specified above.

```
df:
          Source Destination
0  10.120.160.71  172.1.12.5
1  10.120.160.71   172.1.1.5
2  10.120.160.72  172.1.12.6
3  10.120.160.72   172.1.1.6

df = df.set_index(['Source','Destination'])

df.to_excel('df.xlsx')

          Source Destination
0  10.120.160.71  172.1.12.5
1                 172.1.1.5
2  10.120.160.72  172.1.12.6
3                 172.1.1.6
```

Comment: Yes it seems I need a numeric column. It finds the fist one with values for all Source IP and just reports it with the Pivot.  Your solve throws me an error telling me explicitly there is no number column to aggregate on.  So you've put me on the right track.  I've added a same of the data to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but I solved it by doing this

df4 = df4.drop(["Connections"], axis=1)

Then the write works (sort of it it starts in row 2)